# Start to develop android application with NetBeans

Tags: android, netbeans-7

I have just installed NetBeans IDE 7.0.1 and setting up android sdk on it successfully. ( I did setup levels step by step from [here](http://www.techjail.net/starting-programming-for-android-with-netbeans.html). After that, i create the Android Virtual Device ( **AVD** ) from `Android Virtual Device Manager`. So, i create an Android project on netbeans and edit the Main file like below :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("HelloWorld");
        setContentView(tv);
    }
}
```

But the result of running not changed! (It is like below image!) What can i do to test my application successfully ?

[image]

**[EDIT]:** I wait it to complete, so it shows me :

[image]

Comment: This is the initialization window of the Android AVD. You should be patient and wait till the emulator is fully started (You should see the normal android home screen). See the LogCat-window to check wheter your emulator has crashed or not.

Comment: restart/re-launch your emulator first. after that run your app.

Comment: The picture you show is the emulator still booting. Did you ever wait for it to complete?

Comment: @All: Please check the EDIT, i expect it to show me HelloWorld! text!

Comment: First time it take near abt 2-3 minutes.Wait u will get it.

Comment: I wait for it! After some minutes, it shows me Android OS! How can i see the result of running my program ? :-/

Comment: @ Hossein Mobasher : Unlock it..After few seconds your app will run automatically else you choose your app in the list.

Comment: @BabuThangavel : It didn't run automatically! and i can not find my program in menu :-/

Comment: @ Hossein Mobasher : Try it in some other emulator version

Answer (score 1):

Like people commented, If the log cat shows the emulator has completed then wait for the emulator to start it, this can take anywhere from a couple minutes to a 5 minutes depending on your computer,  Now im not sure about net beans but in exlipse the hello world comes set up once you create a new project.  Please wait atleast 5 minutes for your emulator to start up, if it doesnt then repost it could be an abd issuse and you might just have to restart your abd or re download it

Answer (score 1):

wait a minute , where is the layout file for your activity , it should be in `onCreate()` after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Comment: setContentView() needs a view or view layout resource to work, he's doing it with setContentView(tv);

Answer (score 1):

Working on Emulators can be really slow on some computers. Remember emulator needs their own portion of memory from your existing RAM, so if the emulator doesn't turn up in few minutes, try to change the Memory of your AVD (Android Virtual Device).

Although irrelevant, but I'd suggest you to have an android device, instead of using Emulators. I use them only to test UI/Layouts in multiple screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You should be patient waiting for the android booting emulator. I have some suggestion may be could help you determine your problem.

First, close Netbeans and then try to run emulator via command prompt (if you are using Windows). Follow bellow steps:

- Open command prompt and then navigate to emulator directory (inside Android SDK installation)
- type `emulator -avd your_avd_name` if you do not know or If you are in doubt about the name of the emulator then you could type `emulator -avd -list-avds` to see all list of emulator. After that please wait some moment when emulator is booting.
- If not working, try run emulator using -wipe-data parameter. `emulator -avd your_avd_name -wipe-data`. This command will run emulator and wipe data saved on emulator.
  -if not working, try to run emulator without animation boot. `emulator -avd your_avd_name -no-boot-anim`. This command will run emulator without animation on boot.

Another suggestion:
 - Try to using other emulator rather than emulator packaged within
   Android SDk. For Exampe try using Genymotion Emulator.
 - Try to using ADB USB Debugging (use physical android phone).

Cheers
Nusagates